# Extend Gradle Task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Now in project i am using [gradle plugin](https://github.com/x2on/gradle-hockeyapp-plugin) for hockeyapp.

I want to extend **task** from this plugin and change some logic. I declared class for my task in **buildSrc** folder.

Here my code:

```
class CustomHockeyAppUploadTask : HockeyAppUploadTask() {}
```

**HockeyAppUploadTask** is class that represents task from **gradle plugin**. The problem is that i can't access this task from my code.

Is it possible to do?

P.S: I am using kotlin dsl for gradle.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access this task"?

Comment: @LukasKörfer android studio does not see at all this class. i can't import this class.

Comment: Do you have a `build.gradle` file in your `buildSrc` directory?